# Xamarin Forms - Close the app through PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My question is simple:
Is there an easy way to close an app from the PCL project?

If not necessary I would not code any OS-specific functionalities, but I cannot find any useful method that I could call from an event that is called when I click on a Close button in my MasterDetailPage. So in pseudo this is what I would like to do:

```
MasterDetailPage.xaml.cs:

void DeleteButtonOnClick(...)
{
   ...
   App.Close();
}
```

Comment: Explicitly closing an app is a general no-no in Mobile.  Let the OS (or the User) manage the app lifecycle.  Apple explicitly forbids this, and Google strongly discourages it.

Comment: I am a Windows Phone user and I always close all the apps I opened, because specific apps (mainly games) cannot be started when too many things are in the memory. Even if this full-close is not advised, I would still allow the user to exit the app (does that mean minimizing the app?), so he does not need to press the back button several times.

Comment: While I agree with @Jason that this is not a very good idea, the only way to do it from the PCL is to throw an uncaught exception. Terrible idea...but it will work.

Comment: That would show a XY stopped working message, would not it?